# Can this be considered an API?

Tags: php, rest, api

I'm writing my first API, but I think I screwed it up from the design. It's a simple CRUD API which behave like this:

- READ: `/api/data` gets redirected to `api.php?data1=data`. POST variables: user, HMAC, action (read).
- CREATE: `/api/new`gets redirected to `api.php`. POST variables user, HMAC, action, data1, data2, data3.
- DELETE: `api/delete` gets redirected to `api.php`. POST variables: user, HMAC, action, data1.
- UPDATE: `api/update` gets redirected to `api.php`. POST variables: user, HMAC, action, data1, data2, data3.

Then in my `api.php` I have for `if` statements for performing each action based on `$_POST['action']`

However... is this an API? The READ behaves as expected I guess, but not sure if the other methods comply to the definition of an API.

Comment: "API" does not have a precise definition, and I'm not aware of a vague definition of it that would exclude a typical REST setup like this. What definition are you thinking of?

Comment: If you send a GET request for _read_ which includes POST parameters... yes, you're doing something wrong. POST requests should by convention only be used for _create_ in a CRUD API.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter actually you have no clue on this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An API, probably yes. A REST API probably not.

If it works and another program can interact with it then it's an API (Application Programming Interface)  IMHO.

However, your implementation can probably be improved.

It looks like you are going Restful. Typically HTTP methods (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE...) and used on a single URL that represents your entity.

Example:

GET /api/v1/widgets/1234

Would return widget with id=1234

POST /api/v1/gadgets

Creates a new widget. Data/payload would be sent in the body of the post as form data, json etc.

In your PHP code (or whatever language) use the HTTP method in the incoming request context to switch to a function to handle each method.

This is basically an MVC type pattern. There'll be plenty of articles on the Web that explain this in detail.

Generally these days there are frameworks that make life easier. Examples are ASP.NET Web API and Restify for NodeJS. Unfortunately, I don't know much about the PHP ecosystem. This article may help 
http://www.gajotres.net/best-available-php-restful-micro-frameworks/